# SharePoint Online, how to put site visits to home page

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jquery

I want to add the number of site views to Home page. This number displays on the page of site content by default.

[image]

I use iframe to add this part to home page. But the page which in the iframe always has scroll. (**Not scroll of iframe**) 
How could I hide this **scroll of page** ? Or there are other ways to put this number to home page ?

```
    <div style="border: none; overflow: hidden;max-width: 420px;">
<iframe id="SiteVisits" scrolling="no"
  src="https://domain/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx?view=14" style="border: 0px none; margin-left: -50px; height: 796px; margin-top: -330px; width: 340px;">
    </iframe>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for site visits count if you put site contents page in an iframe will not be an ideal solution. It would be better to create a component using a rest api call.

Here is the query to get the information required for site visits.

```
_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/search/query?querytext='*'&querytemplate='(WebId:" + _spPageContextInfo.webId + " OR WebId:" + webId with our braces + ") AND (contentclass:STS_Site OR contentclass:STS_Web)'&rowlimit=1&bypassresulttypes=false&selectproperties='Title,Path,Filename,Created,LastModifiedTime,LinkingUrl,ParentLink,WebId,UniqueID,ViewsLifeTime,ViewsLifeTimeUniqueUsers,ViewsRecent,ViewsRecentUniqueUsers,ViewsLastMonths1,ViewsLastMonths1Unique,ViewsLast7Days,ViewsLast6Days,ViewsLast5Days,ViewsLast4Days,ViewsLast3Days,ViewsLast2Days,ViewsLast1Days,ViewsLast7DaysUniqueUsers,ViewsLast6DaysUniqueUsers,ViewsLast5DaysUniqueUsers,ViewsLast4DaysUniqueUsers,ViewsLast3DaysUniqueUsers,ViewsLast2DaysUniqueUsers,ViewsLast1DaysUniqueUsers'&SourceId='8413cd39-2156-4e00-b54d-11efd9abdb89'"
```

The example should be as follows

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='*'&querytemplate='(WebId:{0aec79ea-0f5c-4f2f-a1ca-74b3af08bcad} OR WebId:0aec79ea-0f5c-4f2f-a1ca-74b3af08bcad) AND (contentclass:STS_Site OR contentclass:STS_Web)'&rowlimit=1&bypassresulttypes=false&selectproperties='Title,Path,Filename,Created,LastModifiedTime,LinkingUrl,ParentLink,WebId,UniqueID,ViewsLifeTime,ViewsLifeTimeUniqueUsers,ViewsRecent,ViewsRecentUniqueUsers,ViewsLastMonths1,ViewsLastMonths1Unique,ViewsLast7Days,ViewsLast6Days,ViewsLast5Days,ViewsLast4Days,ViewsLast3Days,ViewsLast2Days,ViewsLast1Days,ViewsLast7DaysUniqueUsers,ViewsLast6DaysUniqueUsers,ViewsLast5DaysUniqueUsers,ViewsLast4DaysUniqueUsers,ViewsLast3DaysUniqueUsers,ViewsLast2DaysUniqueUsers,ViewsLast1DaysUniqueUsers'&SourceId='8413cd39-2156-4e00-b54d-11efd9abdb89'
```

The sum of visitors count is equal to visits count

```
var viewsCount = ViewsLast7Days + ViewsLast6Days + ViewsLast5Days + ViewsLast4Days + ViewsLast3Days + ViewsLast2Days + ViewsLast1Days
```

You can create a complete component using JavaScript/jQuery, AJAX, HTML, and CSS.

Comment: all those values are null for me, what could be the reason?